# specific view orientation for specific views using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, orientation

I've searched and haven't found an up to date swift alternative to this question. I have in total eight views in my application, I want the first three to be locked in to portrait. the rest can rotate willingly. How can i achieve this in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is for each to be governed by a different view controller, and for these to be *presented* view controllers. A presented view controller is in charge of the app's possible orientations (by implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations`).

Comment: they are all governed by their own view controller, so what coding should i add?

Comment: Do you know what a presented view controller is?

Comment: yes , so what code should i implement? and where should it be implemented? in the apps delegate or?

Comment: It really seems to me that unless you don't understand some of the words I've used, I've answered the question quite clearly and completely.

Comment: maybe i have a mis understanding of a presented view controller. how do i make each view controller a presented one

Comment: By saying `presentViewController:...` when you want to show its view.